# How can I have a software access files on the cloud

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, cloud

So I have a small company with plenty of documents and I want to set up an archiving system. I have several employees with different levels of permissions to access the files on the server. This will serve as an archive system plus a management system, as employees can read and write files (depending on the permission) for a certain project, then the admin can prevent access to certain directory (i.e. project).

So after some research I think the best idea is to have a cloud-based NAS in which a user can have locally by giving the correct username and password. Then a software will access these files (which are now local) and can display some data (e.g. project progress, minutes of meetings), or the user can access the files directly.

Does any of this make sense? I mean is that what NAS can actually do and can it be done on the cloud? and can users access the file system (with restrictions) given username and password (much like if it were a network). Is there a better alternative for my purposes?

To the best of my knowledge, I can, instead, create a software that accesses the cloud directly, but how can I get the users to write files and be stored on the cloud? won't that be more complicated to implement? Can I use an RDMS for it? I've used it before but never for files.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend using google cloud storage for your requirements. You can collaborate and share files between several employees with different levels of permissions by creating a project and buckets on GCP. You can find more information and detailed steps on [this link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/collaboration).